# Homomorphism between rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is a homomorphism between the following rings:

The collection **P**(Z) of subsets of $Z$, with addition $A ⊕ B := A∆B$ and
multiplication $A◦ B := A ∩ B$, and the integers mod 2.

Comment: Do you literally mean "what is a homomorphism?" or do you mean that you want an explicit homomorphism?

Comment: You only provided *one* ring. What would be the other one?

Comment: @CaptainLama I meant an example of an explicit function, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @Berci It's the integers mod 2, it's in the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For any set $Z$, the ring homomorphisms $P(Z)\to \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ correspond to the *ultrafilters* of $Z$.

For a specific example, let $z\in Z$ arbitrary, and send $S\mapsto 0$ if $z\notin S$ and $S\mapsto 1$ if $z\in S$.

Comment: Sorry but I have not encountered filters yet. As a matter of fact, I haven't even encountered homomorphisms. All I wanted to prove is that symmetric difference on the first ring is associative, but without getting into long computations with set algebra, so I thought I could use a homomorphism between the two rings I mentioned instead, and therefore show that addition on the first set "behaves" like addition on the integers mod 2, which is associative.

Comment: Your idea does not work, because unless the homomorphism is injective (which would not be the case here), you cannot deduce associativity on the source from associativity on the target.

Comment: @CaptainLama Oh I see... as I said, I'm very new to homomorphisms, so I didn't know this. Then I guess I'll do the laborious proof with set operations. Thank you!

Comment: @JBuck Note that symmetric difference can be calculated 'pointwise' by logical operation XOR, just like union by OR or intersection by AND, and observe that XOR is just the addition of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. And this is basically proven once the given examples are verified to be homomorphisms.